# How to reduce the number of Parameters in method of POJO?

Tags: methods, pojo

In any Method in JAVA, 
How can I reduce the number of Parameters ?

Suppose, 
MEthod 
m1() {
}

in any method in POJO, how to reduce the number of parameters

Comment: You can create object and pass it to the method.

Comment: can you please give an Example ?